# How to remove clickHandler which already added to Label?

Tags: java, gwt, click, handler

I am using GWT/JAVA for development. I have following problem:
I want to remove the ClickHandler from Label which I already added to the Label.

I tried removeClickListener() but it is deprecated, so I can not find another solution to do this.

Please let me know if anyone found the solution..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know GWT, but here is what you can do (from the API).

```
HandlerRegistration reg = label.addClickHandler(clickHandler);

reg.removeHandler();
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using wrong method. the right one is.

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label.addClickHandler(ClickHandler)
```

On this method call, there is a instance of `HandlerRegistration` returned. There is a method that is

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration.removeHandler()
```

Answer (score -1):

**addClickHandler( new ... )** (and every other "**add...Handler(**") returns a HandlerRegistration interface.

You have to register this handler.
Therefore you'll be able to remove the clickHandler at any time.

```
    HandlerRegistration handler = null;

    private void updateMyInformationLabel(){
         if(handler != null){ 
              // previous onClickHandler removed
              handler.removeHandler(); 
         }
         // adding a new action on label click 
         handler = myInformationLabel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                           // something done once
                       }
                   });        
    }
```

Comment: why -1 to the answer ?